# Webrtc sdp exchange stuck

Tags: webrtc, sdp, signaling

Does anyone knows a walkaround, ideea or solution for the following webrtc sdp exchange issues. (I'm using an async messaging service to send my sdp candidates from A<->B.)

In the same time :
  A <- OFFER -> B  (both are creating and send its own sdp(offer) to the other peer).

The problem is that after the sdp arrives to the destination it can't be setted (in order to create an answer) because the destination will be in state "khavelocaloffer" (which waits for an answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not have both sides create an offer and expect things to work. One side needs to offer, the other side needs to answer.

Comment: And how the part that needs to answer can renegotiate? It should make an offer request to the offerer?  ( eg. in case he removes its video stream)

Comment: yes, in that case the roles of offerer and answerer change. https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/upgrade/ shows a sample for renegotation -- however not the role change.